# Why would a file put in shared drive between the Gennymotion emulator and host machine, when deleted does not go to recycle bin of the host machine?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whats the logic behind a file put in shared drive between the Genny motion emulator and host machine, when deleted does not go to recycle bin of the host machine ?

Can anybody tell whether It is a choice/feature by design of that particular tool (Gennymotion) Or Is it generic to any emulators using a shared directory with the host file system ?

If it is generic why not follow the pattern of a two stage deletion process as usual ? Are there any particular advantages of not doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

The recycle bin/trash can are window manager (note the lower case) convenience. It allow for the average user to say 'oh I didn't mean to destroy it' and bring it back in a straight forward manner. The window manager program (for Windows, Mac and Linux) which handles where to stash a file ready to be 'emptied/shredded'.

If you use the command line then you would have encountered commands like 'del' or 'rm' which delete or remove the file from the filesystem with the assumption that the user knows there is no easy way back.

For most every IO library that a developer would use in any language (C,C++,Python,C#,Java,Ruby,Swift) 'delete' or equivalent means remove from the file system. Since you, the developer, used the 'delete' call you meant that behavior and not some 200 popup dialogs asking for 'are you sure' - unless you wrote the behavior to be that way too.